# Trouble with graphical layout

Tags: android, eclipse, layout

When I am trying to look at my graphical layout this message appears in the error log:

> activity_main.xml: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout.

How would I go about correcting this so my code will work correctly?
I have changed around the `alignParentLeft` and set them to true. I have also messed around with the `align_above` and `align_below` which hasn't helped. I'm not sure what my problem is.

Here is my code:

```
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >


         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
            android:text="Number of cups" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginRight="23dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

          <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/go"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/cream"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:text="To Go" />



        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cream"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/sugar"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:text="Leave room for cream" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/sugar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/drinks"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
            android:text="Leave room for sugar" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/drinks"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sugar"
            android:layout_above="@+id/flavoring"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/coffee"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Coffee($2.50)" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/cappuccino"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="Cappucino($4.50)" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/espresso"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Espresso($4.50)" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/latte"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Latte($4.50)" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/iced_latte"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Iced Latte($5.00)" />
        </RadioGroup>



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/flavoring"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/chocolate"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
            android:text="Flavoring" />

         <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chocolate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/cherry"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
            android:text="Chocolate" />

          <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cherry"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/vanilla"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
            android:text="Cherry" />

           <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/vanilla"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cherry"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
            android:text="Vanilla" />

    <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >


        </ScrollView>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are your problems

```
  <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/sugar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/drinks"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:text="Leave room for sugar" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/drinks"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sugar"
        android:layout_above="@+id/flavoring"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
```

You are telling `sugar` to be above `drinks` and for `drinks` to be below `sugar`. You can only do one of these or they get into an infinite circle. So remove `android:layout_below="@+id/sugar"` from `drinks RadioGroup`.

I don't see yet if you have this anywhere else but if you do then you will need to fix those, also. You can't tell a `View` to be above another and tell that `View` to be below the same `View`...same with left and right.

**Edit found another**

```
 <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cherry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/vanilla"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:text="Cherry" />

       <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/vanilla"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cherry"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:text="Vanilla" />
```

You have the same thing going on here. You will need to remove the `above` or the `below` from one of these.

Comment: Thanks for the quickness. I removed that from my code, but the error message is still there. Could the checkboxes be the problem?

Comment: Thank you sir. That has fixed my code. I'll beware of the belows they are throwing me off.

Comment: Its not necessarily the `below` but its the `below` and `above` on `Views` that reference each other.

Comment: Ahh, well regardless I will pay more attention.